# AddHandlers in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to dynamically creating `dropdownList` boxes, and I want trying to add `AddHandlers` to them so that when an item is selected in them, it fires an event, but also need to pass another variable, and I don't know what to put as the parameter for `system.EventArgs`. Please look at the code below to see the problem I'm having.

```
AddHandler inputDrop.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf selOption(inputDrop, ???, var1)

Protected Sub selOption(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs, ByVal tableCount As String)

End Sub
```

What do I put (???) right here.

**The error**:

> is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event.

Answer (score 6):

In addition what [Mike C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18720593/142637) already explained, if the signature of the event handler does not match the event, you can always wrap the event handler in another method, for example an anonymous one:

```
Protected Sub selOption(ender As Object, e As System.EventArgs, somestring As String)

End Sub

...

For i = 1 To 10
    Dim cbox = new ComboBox()
    Dim number = i ' local copy to prevent capturing of i '
    AddHandler cbox.SelectedIndexChanged, Sub(s, e) selOption(s, e, "Hi! I am Number " & number)
Next
```

Now, when the index of the last `ComboBox` changes, the `somestring` parameter passed to `selOption` will be `Hi! I am Number 10`, while it will be `Hi! I am Number 1` for the first `ComboBox` etc.

Answer (score 5):

When you register an event handler, you don't specify the arguments at that time.  You're basically just setting a reference to a delegate that will handle the event when it is raised.

```
AddHandler inputDrop.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf selOption
```

The most important thing is that the method signature of the event handler matches up exactly with the method signature defined by the event.  I'm not sure that your method would work because you have that extra `tableCount` parameter specified.  You will need to modify your method signature to be:

```
Protected Sub selOption(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
```

I'm basing that off the definition of `SelectedIndexChanged` for Winforms.  This event could be defined differently in another technology, such as ASP.net or WPF.  Or if this is some custom class, it could be an entirely different signature altogether.  However, typically most event handlers have a similar structure of a `sender` (the instance that raises the event) and some event arguments.

Then when `inputDrop` fires it's event (when the selected item changes), your code will get automatically called.  The arguments passed to this method will be passed directly from `inputDrop`, you do not have to specify them.

Also, your `AddHandler` statement must exist inside a method or code block, it can't just live in the class definition.  It's a statement that must be executed like any other piece of code, it's not a declaration.

Answer (score 4):

And there is yet another way of doing it. Inherit the control in question and add a property like this:

```
Public Class MyComboBox : Inherits ComboBox
  Public Property tableCount As String
End Class
```

Then set your custom value and add a handler as you would for a regular ComboBox:

```
combo.tableCount = tableCount
AddHandler combo.Click, AddressOf combo_Click
```

Inside `combo_Click`, CType `sender` to your inherited type, and get the value you stored previously:

```
Private Sub combo_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
  Debug.WriteLine(CType(sender, WorkflowActionBox).tableCount)
End Sub
```

You will need to replace current usages of `ComboBox` with those of `MyComboBox`, where you want the new property to be available. Simple as opening your designer file and doing find/replace.